# Getting "Access to sendgrid.com was denied" (HTTP ERROR 403) trying to access sendgrid dashboard

Tags: dashboard, heroku, sendgrid

I recently added the Sendgrid add-on to my (free tier) Heroku app and now when I click on it on the add-ons page to open the dasdhboard, I get an error:

[image: Sendgrid dashboard error]

I tried opening it with `heroku addons:open` as recommended at https://help.heroku.com/NQLJHM1C/not-authorized-errors-trying-to-log-into-an-add-ons-sso-using-dashboard and that doesn't work either.

Also, I see this in the logs when I try to send an email through Sendgrid from my Heroku app:

`2020-03-15T18:09:24.297453+00:00 app[web.1]: [42e2afe7-65cb-48ef-b6b9-8d08302031bd] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I faced totally same problem.
In my case, I contacted SendGrid support and asked to activate my SendGrid account.
In two working days, they reactivated my account with their apology.
And now my app successfully send email.
Please try this. Good luck.

Here is SendGrid support:
https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 2):

It seems SendGrid's Heroku integration is not working (neither via the link nor with the credentials in the config).

You'd have to contact support which you can't do on a free tier, however, here's a form to submit login related issues: https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/requests/new/submit They will get back to you with questions about your business, and the back-and-forth takes up to multiple days.

If you're looking for a quick email integration with Heroku, SendGrid is probably not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan, when you add the send grid add on to Heroku, it creates two environment/config variables.

I suggest that you go to this URL https://app.sendgrid.com/login and try to log in with these credentials.

Your account might be locked because you did not verify your email at sendgrid end, which a required step. Once you do that it should be work.

If you are not able to log in, then there is an issue at sendgrid end and you may need to contact their support.

[image: Heroku Addons]

Comment: It won't let me log in. It says "You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact Support." Except I can't do that because people on the free SendGrid tier aren't allowed to contact support, they can only post questions here on StackExchange.